# Javascript Date.Parse blows up on Russian Dates

Tags: javascript, date, localization

We have a web application that gets its data from a certain database. The product writing to that database has been localized to RUSSIAN, thus its data, in particular the dates had been localized too.

We encountered a problem where our DATES would not show on our application. We traced the problem to an invalid Date.parse() javascript call.

Example:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var value = Date.parse("01/31/2009 08:00:00 AM");
document.write(value);
</script>

</body>
```

Would return 1260576000000.

However,

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var value = Date.parse("31.01.2009 08:00:00 AM");
document.write(value);
</script>

</body>
```

Would return NaN.

Is there a way to parse localized dates in Javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in function does not support i18n. Use a toolkit, auch as [dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/), to parse and output dates.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the sort of situation where I would find a friendly developer who knows Regex. Regex should be able to turn one type of date format to another before you parse the string.

Comment: You're right... We can massage the date to fit the parse criteria. However, that would only work if we're only working with Russian dates. But that's not the case, we are localizing in 5 different languages.